# Rediffmail Contact fetch in iOS application

Tags: ios, contacts

is there any way to fetch Rediffmail Contacts to iOS application.

I have done with Gmail but not getting any reference for Rediffmail.

If there is a way then please let me know how can i do it?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried.

Comment: I am not familiar with Rediff, but there seems to be an API. http://developers.rediff.com/wiki/doku.php

Comment: @JohanKarlsson : I havnt tried anything for rediff , i did same for gmail

Comment: @JohanKarlsson: I am going through  developers.rediff.com/wiki/doku.php